# MySQL basic trigger - not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER clean
AFTER INSERT ON `mecze_druzyny`
begin
DELETE * FROM bramki;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

Which should be ran just after following:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO mecze_druzyny (id_druzyny, id_meczu, gospodarz) VALUES (
        :team2, 
        :lastmatch, 
        :gospodarz)";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql2);
$stmt->bindParam(':team2', $id2, PDO::PARAM_INT);       
$stmt->bindParam(':lastmatch', $last_match, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->bindParam(':gospodarz', $a=0, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin
>       DELETE * FROM bramki' at line 3

Comment: this is wrong syntax `DELETE * FROM bramki` read up on the function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: But it's still not working without "*"

Comment: I can guarantee you, it will never work with `*`

Comment: As I wrote - I've removed "*" and trigger is still not working.'

Comment: Your delimiter handling looks off a little, and it creates successfully without a "FOR EACH ROW"?

Comment: read the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER clean AFTER INSERT ON mecze_druzyny
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM 'bramki';
  END;
Still not working...

Comment: `delete` deletes entire records. `delete *` implies you're trying to delete individual fields, which is not possible. `delete from ...` is the proper syntax.

Comment: next time, don't bother reading the manual. It makes others gain rep points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Delimiters to make it correct. Here is the correct syntax to do so:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER clean
AFTER INSERT
   ON mecze_druzyny FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DELETE  FROM bramki;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: *Borrowed from the manual Sam* - @JayBlanchard https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Should I delete my answer? so that you can give some other way to solve the syntax problem.

Comment: Yeah may be it solved the problem. do you have any other way to do so?

Comment: that is the syntax, so I can't make up anything else. Keep this and OP accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

It's an error with your delete syntax.

Get rid of the * so you're left with

`DELETE FROM bramki`

A typical delete will be in the format

`DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ...` -- the WHERE clause is optional here

Comment: This will delete all records from the "bramki table"

Comment: It should indeed delete everything from "bramki" table. But it's still not working without "*"
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin
DELETE FROM bramki' at line 3

Comment: Probably just? Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.